# Update clob column with xml value in oracle

Tags: xml, database, oracle

I have an xml with below structure which is stored as a clob column in a table.

I have to update the Zipcode and City fields to 1000 and Abcd wherever the existing node contains a Zipcode 95813.

There can be multiple address node with same city and Zipcode.

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

```
<Employee>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>26</Age>
    <Addresses>
        <Address>
            <Street>Street1</Street>
            <City>Sacramento</City>
            <ZipCode>95813</ZipCode>
        </Address>
        <Address>
            <Street>Street2</Street>
            <City>Los Angeles</City>
            <ZipCode>95300</ZipCode>
        </Address>
    </Addresses>
</Employee>
```

expected output

```
<Employee>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>26</Age>
    <Addresses>
        <Address>
            <Street>Street1</Street>
            <City>Abcd</City>
            <ZipCode>1000</ZipCode>
        </Address>
        <Address>
            <Street>Street2</Street>
            <City>Los Angeles</City>
            <ZipCode>95300</ZipCode>
        </Address>
    </Addresses>
</Employee>
```

I have already tried updatexml function but didn’t find an option to update specific nodes based on condition in
updatexml

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS version.

Comment: Read up about UPDATEXML function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

Oracle documentation [recommends to use XQuery to update XML](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb04cre.htm#ADXDB0440)

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=633487b73e16c59d369448387dc0971a)

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
CREATE TABLE HOLDS_XML
(xml_col XMLTYPE)
XMLTYPE xml_col STORE AS SECUREFILE BINARY XML;

INSERT INTO HOLDS_XML (xml_col)
VALUES (xmltype('<Employee>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>26</Age>
    <Addresses>
        <Address>
            <Street>Street1</Street>
            <City>Sacramento</City>
            <ZipCode>95813</ZipCode>
        </Address>
        <Address>
            <Street>Street2</Street>
            <City>Los Angeles</City>
            <ZipCode>95300</ZipCode>
        </Address>
    </Addresses>
</Employee>'));
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
select * from  HOLDS_XML;

UPDATE HOLDS_XML
SET xml_col = XMLQuery('copy $i := $p1 
modify(
  replace value of node $i/Employee/Addresses/Address[ZipCode="95813"]/City with $p2,
  replace value of node $i/Employee/Addresses/Address[ZipCode="95813"]/ZipCode with $p3
)
return $i'
PASSING xml_col AS "p1", 'Abcd' AS "p2", '1000' AS "p3"
RETURNING CONTENT)
WHERE XMLExists('$p/Employee/Addresses/Address[ZipCode="95813"]'
PASSING xml_col AS "p"
);

-- after
select * from  HOLDS_XML;
```

Comment: Also works with a CLOB (rather than XMLType) column, which seems to be what the OP is saying, with minor tweaks - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9aee71569d5a562d358e6536b8b4c9f9), using XMLSerialize rather than getCLOB to keep indentation.